# Создание массива

Tags: python, массивы

Как создать двумерный массив, в котором каждое число являеться отдельным массивом. Пример такого массива

```py
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [[1,2,3,4], [6,5], [7,8,9]]
```

а это что - не создание такого массива?

```
arr = [[i] for i in range(1, 10)]
```

вот так можно создать массив `[[1], [2], [3], ...]`

P.S.

вы конкретнее описывайте что именно надо то :)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант. Создать список из 2 элементов, каждый элемент кторого список из 2 элементов. В общем список списков.

```py
a = [[x for x in range(2)] for y in range(2)]
print(a)  # [[0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

Пожалуй один из немногих случаев когда генераторы списков полезны.